# Using jquery mobile to create an app

Tags: jquery, iphone, mobile

I am a beginner with jquery mobile and I want to create an app, for iphone, that initially will have a box where the user will input a value. Then the app should switch to another page where it will generate a number of forms based on the value inputted by the user. Is it possible to do that? Do I use php for that or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Visit this site [http://jquerymobile.com/](http://jquerymobile.com)

Here **codiqa** is tool integrated, where you can design and code jquery application on the fly. Also you can inspect the code to understand background functionality and implementation.

All documentation are also available through this site.

Comment: I looked this website before but I can't find how can I pass a data value, inputted by the user, from one page to another. Do I use something else for that?